# "Boundary" thickness in HighlightImage

Tags: bugs, image-processing, image

**Bug introduced in 11 or earlier and persisting through 11.3**

> CASE:4076121

---

I'm having a hard time to understand how I can use `HighlightImage` and only draw the boundary of a binary image with a thickness of exactly one pixel. The documentation suggests that I can use

```
HighlightImage[
 img,
 {{"Boundary", thickness}, Binarize[img]}
]
```

but that doesn't work properly. Here is a small example that shows the behavior on Mathematica 11.3 on OS X

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLGJC.png"];
Manipulate[
 With[{img = ImageResize[img, size]},
  Show[HighlightImage[
    img,
    {{"Boundary", thickness}, Binarize[img]}
    ], ImageSize -> 1024
   ]
  ], {size, 100, 500, 1}, {thickness, .1, 10}
 ]
```

As you will see, the `thickness` setting has no influence and if you scale the image up with the `size` slider, then the boundary thickness covers many pixels

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I noticed this too, but didn't complain to WRI. It changed in some recent version. It seemed intentional ...

Comment: @Szabolcs It seems like they broke this functionality when refactoring the code (see my answer below) - no idea why they did it in the first place though

Comment: @Szabolcs always complain. It may get fixed ))

Comment: @LukasLang it is indeed a bug that slipped through the testing. I just committed a fix. As you where wondering, the reason is that *directives* like "Boundary" should change the behaviour of all the subsequent primitives, resetting other custom scopes like "Blur".

Comment: @Batracos That's great to hear! Regarding the reasoning: Thanks for the insight. I was also wondering why some definitions are only loaded by `toGraphicsPrimitiveDefinitions` - is this something entirely related to other internals or is there some reason behind it that could also be relevant for custom code?

Comment: It's only relevant to the current implementation of HighlightImage. You have so many definitions for `toGraphicsPrimitive` because it must mimic the behaviour of Graphics (directive/primitives, soft failures, etc.) plus accept some custom specifications (more are coming...) while being modular enough so that I don't get crazy when there's the need to add support for more things—compared to Graphics, there's native support for list of points, for regions and for images; plus whatever may appear in the image domain. It's very tricky and every now and then I feel the need of retouching it.

Answer (score 11):

The following fixes the issue:

```
If[$VersionNumber>=11.3,
  Begin["Image`InteractiveDump`"],
  Begin["Image`ColorOperationsDump`"]
];
HighlightImage;
DownValues[toGraphicsPrimitive] = DownValues[toGraphicsPrimitive] /. 
  {HoldPattern[pre_; Sequence[s__]] :> ((pre; {s}) /. {res__} :> res)};
End[];
```

[image]

#### Why does this work

It appears that at some point, every definition of `` Image`InteractiveDump`toGraphicsPrimitive `` (`toGP` in the following) was prepended with  `` `toGraphicsPrimitiveDefinitions `` (so `toGP[args]:=rhs` became `toGP[args]:=(toGPD;rhs)`). It looks like this loads some more definitions for `toGP`, but no idea what the purpose of doing it this way is...

The issue is that the signature of `toGP` that handles `{"Boundary", thickness_}` returned a `Sequence`, which is evaluated prematurely by the `CompoundExpression` that got wrapped around. The above fix resolves this issue by only introducing the `Sequence` head after the `CompundExpression` is done evaluating. (please leave a comment if you find a more straightforward solution to protect the `Sequence` head)

Comment: Thanks for spelunking for me. I was really worried I simply use it wrong somehow. I'm looking at it in detail later. +1

Comment: @Mathe172 - Please how to use the fix, where to put the Begin-End sequence? Is it a procedure, shall I call it before HighligtImage? Thanks in advance

Comment: @CJoe Yes, just execute it once before you call `HighlightImage`. For example, you can add it as first line to your notebook

Comment: @Mathe172 - Im sorry, I cant make it working. Either it does not have influence or the Mathematica crashes (on Pi3). Would you be so kind and put the working code of that your example above?

Comment: @CJoe What version of MMA are you using? The fix might not be applicable to older versions without any changes. For the example in the answer: What I did to get that was to open a fresh session, execute the code in my answer, and then the code from the question (the one starting with `img = …`)

Comment: @CJoe Mathe172's fix works only on 11.3. I tested it on OS X and Linux and there still might be a difference on your RPi. On 11.2 the above fix doesn't work and it seems they broke it in a different way in this version or refactored the code again in 11.3. If I have some time, I will update my question with a very simple boundary highlighting that works purely on the pixels.

Comment: @Mathe172 , halirutan - Im running the Math. v. 11.2.0.0 on my RPi3; I did what Mathe mentions - running the Begin-End code and the code which I want the Boundary respects thickness, but no influence :(  . The Bounday in my case hides small detail behind it , I need to thinn the Boundary line or make it translucent

Comment: @CJoe,@halirutan I've updated the fix to work for 11.2 as well. Essentially, they've changed the internal context, which is why the fix didn't apply correctly in pre 11.3 versions. Let me know if you still have issues

Comment: @Mathe172 - great! the Boundary thickness works now for me! I can confirm that your fix works for v. 11.2.0.0 . Thank you. (Cannot add one more point to your answer as I already did before and dont have rights for giving more than 1 )

Comment: A simpler fix that however requires changing existing code is to use `... , FaceForm[], EdgeForm[AbsoluteThickness[n]], ...` in place of `{"Boundary", n}`.