# Precision-related error in Audio

Tags: bugs, precision-and-accuracy, sound, machine-precision

**Bug introduced in 11.3 or earlier**

> CASE:4075745

---

I have been experimenting with using `Audio` and associated functions for data acquisition using an external sound card. I came across a bizarre problem with generated sine waves, where jagged teeth would appear in the waveform.

```
ListLinePlot[
  AudioData[
    AudioGenerator[{"Sin", 1000}, 0.1, SampleRate -> 48000]
  ][[1, ;; 100]]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is a problem in the audio itself and not a display or data extraction error, as verified by looking at the output of the sound card on an oscilloscope. This originally occurred when using `AudioGenerator`, but the error persisted when passing an array of `Sin` values to `Audio`.

The problem appears to be caused by `Audio` interpreting high-precision (but not exact) values of 1/2 as 0.25.

```
a = N[{Sin[(25*Pi)/6], 1/2, 0.5, 0.4999999, 0.49999999, Sin[(25.*Pi)/6]}]
(* {0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5} *)

First[AudioData[Audio[a]]]
(* {0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25} *)
```

This error was observed on 11.3 on macOS, but also occurs on Mathematica Online. The issue has been reported to Wolfram support [CASE:4075745].

Comment: By default `Audio` uses 32 bit `maybe try AudioData[Audio[a, "Real"]]`?

Comment: @chuy Thanks for the suggestion, but nope. I tried all available type settings, and the last two are always half the value of the first 4.

Comment: I appreciate that you made a minimal example, but could you include the actual code that generated the sinewave with the jagged teeth as well? I can't reproduce it with simply `First@AudioData@Audio@Table[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10, 0.1}] // ListLinePlot`.

Comment: @MarcoB Good suggestion, done.

Comment: @DanielW Thank you! v. 11.2 works fine ([output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YUwUM.png)), so the problem seems to have been introduced to 11.3.

Comment: This might be OS dependent. `In[104]:= AudioData[Audio[a], "Real32"]

Out[104]= {{0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25}}` is what I get using 11.3 on Windows.

Comment: @MarcoB it only happens at specific frequencies for specific sample rates. There appears to be something special about `Sin[(25.*Pi)/6 + n*Pi]`.

Comment: @DanielW for what values of `n` do you get the problem?

Comment: @MarcoB Integers. There may be others, but it seems to happen for all n in the Integers. `First[AudioData[Audio[Sin[(25.*Pi)/6 + Range[-10, 10]*Pi]]]]` gives a list of +-.0.25.

Comment: As @chuy mentioned, this may be OS and version-dependent. With your code above I get some 0.5, some 0.25. The problem goes away entirely if I use `Audio[..., "Real"]`.

Comment: @DanielW *After* you get an answer from Wolfram acknowledging that this is a bug, please feel free to add the `[bugs]` tag. Additionally, it would be awesome if you edit your question then and include a "bug header" at the very top [like in this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174758/boundary-thickness-in-highlightimage).

Comment: @chuy and You were correct after all, "Real" did fix the problem, if it is typed in correctly, which I did not when testing it. The rounding problem, however, is an actual bug. I just missed getting an earlier solution by not typing carefully.

Answer (score 2):

This has been acknowledged by Wolfram Support as a bug and the developers have been informed. The workaround Support suggested is as @chuy had suggested in the comments, specifying the "Real" type for `Audio`:

```
ListLinePlot[
  AudioData[
    AudioGenerator[{"Sin", 1000}, 0.1, "Real", SampleRate -> 48000]
  ][[1,1 ;; 100]]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
a = N[{Sin[(25*Pi)/6], 1/2, 0.5, 0.4999999, 0.49999999, Sin[(25.*Pi)/6]}];
First[AudioData[Audio[a, "Real"]]]

(* {0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5} *)
```

This workaround failed for me previously because of a silly typographical error.