# Overplot overexposed pixels on image

Tags: image-processing

I have an `image` and want to mark each pixel which has a brightness of 1 with yellow color.

The `image` is (png, 8bit):

[image]

My code to find and mark overexposed pixels:

```
imageData = ImageData[image];

overexposedPositions = Position[imageData, n_ /; n == 1];

x = overexposedPositions[[All, 1]];
y = overexposedPositions[[All, 2]];

data = Transpose[{y, dimImage[[2]] - x}];

Show[image, Graphics[{Yellow, Point[#] & /@ data}]]
```

When I compare these two images I can see that pixels are marked yellow but are not overexposed?! So there must be an error in my code.

How would you solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work as well:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epzrz.png"];
highlighted = ColorReplace[img, White -> Yellow, $MachineEpsilon]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: A very elegant solution. Thank you. How would you highlight with this code e.g. all intensities between 0.4 and 0.8?

Comment: @mrz I would think that is what `ColorReplace[img, 0.6 -> Yellow, 0.2]` does.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Why is in the replacement `$MachineEpsilon` required? In the 8 bit images white is always exactly 1., or not?

Comment: I compared the solution of @Niki Estner with your solution (which is much shorter). In his enlarged example area 5 pixels are overexposed. When I check the same region with `ColorReplace` I see exactly the same result as Niki finds, https://i.imgur.com/VOOyb2K.png, but only when I use `$MachineEpsilon`.

Comment: @mrz: If you read the docs for `ColorReplace`, you'll find: `ColorReplace[image,color] is equivalent to ColorReplace[image,color,0.1].`. So without `$MachineEpsilon` it would replace anything above .9 to `color`.

Answer (score 4):

I'll take a small part of your image, so we can look at individual pixels:

```
image = ImageTake[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epzrz.png"], 100, 
  100]
```

The easiest way to get the positions of all pixels with a certain value is using `ImageValuePositions`:

```
overexposed = ImageValuePositions[image, 1];
Show[image, Graphics[{Red, Point[overexposed]}], ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

It looks as if the overexposed pixels are all marked, and the markers are in the middle of the pixels, at least at this scale. But `Point`s can be smaller or larger than pixels, so I'd prefer overlaying a binary mask over the image:

```
HighlightImage[image, UnitStep[image - 1], ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Sadly, `HighlightImage` is a bit broken in current versions of MMA (["Boundary" thickness in HighlightImage](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174758/boundary-thickness-in-highlightimage)), so if you want *only* the overexposed pixels marked, without a border, you'll have to do it manually:

```
With[{notOverexposed = 1 - UnitStep[image - 1]},
 Image[ColorCombine[{image, notOverexposed*image, 
    notOverexposed*image}], ImageSize -> 600]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. This is very interesting what you say about `HighlightImage`. What I cannot see: how would you for example get a yellow color for highlighting?

Comment: @mrz: in the last code example? It's just basic arithmetic. Yellow is a mixture of green + red. So you have to set the green channel to the same value as the red channel. Then the blue channel is 0 for overexposed pixels -> and they're yellow.

Comment: Merry Christmas Niki. Thank you for your help. Please see my last comment to the answer of C. E.